# how to store three values in data structure python

Tags: python

I have this input: 
node1, node2, similarity

for example :

```
1 2 0.33
1 3 5
1 5 0.8
```

and I want to classify them based on similarity so the result will be :

```
1 3 5
1 5 0.8
1 2 0.33
```

my question is: with data structure is suitable to store these data and how to implement it? ^-^ thank you

Comment: where are you getting the input from ? user input?

Comment: clear up the question as it is kind of confusing. read up on tuples, lists, dictionaries. I think you will want a list of tuples for your approach though, but I'm still not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

List of tuple do the trick :

Let's say this is your input :

```
input = [(1, 2, 0.33), (1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 0.8)]
```

Then to sort it :

```
output = sorted(input, key=lambda tup: tup[2])
```

And you get this :

```
[(1, 2, 0.33), (1, 5, 0.8), (1, 3, 5)]
```

Then you can apply overs method, reverse it, or whatever you want !